# bash trap EXIT $LINENO always 1

Tags: bash, shell, bash-trap

test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
trap 'echo $LINENO' EXIT
/bin/false
```

run

```
$ ./test.sh
1
```

How may I get the actual line number of "/bin/false" instead of always '1'?

Comment: what do you mean with `the actual number of "/bin/false"`? you get `1` which is the result of `echo $LINENO` invoked at `EXIT`

Comment: Can't reproduce, if I run your `test.sh` on my machine, it shows `4` *as expected*.

Comment: [He said he got 12 but we all fail.](https://medium.com/@dirk.avery/the-bash-trap-trap-ce6083f36700)

Comment: I can reproduce the same behavior and landed here looking for the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting 1 because you trap EXIT. Try :

```
trap ... ERR
```

Comment: What if I wanted to get the line number of an EXIT signal without error? Is that possible? I see the same, $LINENO always 1 when trap ... EXIT is called, but the same works with trap .. ERR. However I want to have a generic trap that captures both normal and error exit and handles errors in the trap function.

Comment: @lud, unfortunately, bash reset LINENO before calling trap for EXIT.

Comment: This is not true for all Bash versions. Bash 3 (specifically Bash 3 on macOS) will report the lineno on trap exit (if there was an error and assuming set -o errexit).

Comment: Meaning: although the question is closed and could be expressed otherwise, the desired behavior of OP is working as-is in bash 3. In other bash versions, you can trap both ERR and EXIT, and store the lineno in a variable on ERR - output the value of that variable in EXIT if defined.